# C++ Считать строку из n цифр или всю строку с пробелами

Tags: c++, строки, консоль

Пользователь вводит с клавиатуры символы.
Если он ввёл n-цифр подряд (не нажимая "Enter"), то завершить ввод и вернуть эту строку.
Иначе дождаться, когда он нажмёт "Enter" и вернуть строку с пробелами.
Тип строки std::wstring;
Сейчас считываю строку

```
std::wstring wstr;    
try {
    std::fflush(NULL);
    std::wcin.sync();
}
catch(...){}
std::getline(std::wcin, wstr);
std::fflush(NULL);
```

Comment: А в чём состоит вопрос или проблема?

Comment: Учебное консольное приложение. Если вводится штрих-код (13-цифр), с клавиатуры или со сканера, то возвращается строка с этим кодом, чтобы после сканера не надо было ещё "Enter" нажимать. Или вводится наименование товара, который потом ищется.